# News feed retrieval in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I am trying to access my news feed using the following  code:

```
me?fields=home
```

When I access it in my iOS app, I can only retrieve a few posts.

When I execute it in Graph API explorer to retrieve next page of posts:

```
me?fields=home.until(123456789).limit(25)
```

Where does this id come from? Or how do i retrieve the next set of posts which I can access by clicking on the arrows in the Graph API explorer, through the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found it in the Facebook documentation itself.

1. The section called "Paging" at the following link briefly explains (until and limit) fields.

   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/
2. The following link explains how to get the next page of posts.

   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/